# MySQL: Group unique column into its own array of results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a `subscriptions` table, where users can subscribe to multiple categories. Let's say I have the following data in this table:

**Table Structure and Data:**

```
+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
|  subscription_id  |  user_id  |  category_id  |
+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
|  1                |  40       |  123          |
|  2                |  40       |  120          |
|  3                |  40       |  119          |
|  4                |  37       |  120          |
|  5                |  37       |  119          |
|  6                |  34       |  123          |
+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

I'm attempting to write a MySQL query that'll group the results by `user_id`. Below is a general illustration in JSON (but the output format doesn't matter; JSON is visually easier-to-read IMO for this example).

**Desired Output:**

```
{
    40: [
        {
            subscription_id: 1,
            category_id: 123
        },
        {
            subscription_id: 2,
            category_id: 120
        },
        {
            subscription_id: 3,
            category_id: 119
        }
    ],
    37: [
        {
            subscription_id: 4,
            category_id: 120
        },
        {
            subscription_id: 5,
            category_id: 119
        }
    ],
    34: [
        {
            subscription_id: 6,
            category_id: 123
        }
    ]
}
```

Running a query with `GROUP BY user_id` only returns unique rows.

**Two Questions:**

1. Is the above output possible via a MySQL query or will post-query data manipulation (i.e. loops) be required?
2. If this above output *IS* possible, would it be faster and more efficient to perform post-query manipulation anyway? (Let's assume there are thousands of rows.)

Comment: You could `group_concat` the `category_id ` and `subscription_id`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by chris85 you may do like this. This may work or may not but when you see its results it may give you some idea

```
select *, GROUP_CONCAT(category_id, ' ', subscription_id) from subscriptions GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: `subscription_id` will be lost with this answer, you need to group_concat both.

Comment: have you found some idea from this

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(subscription_id)` as well

Comment: Thanks @chris85 and @Anil Shrestha, the `GROUP_CONCAT` was the missing piece to the puzzle. Cheers!

Comment: You should not use `select *` with `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer would be first select all items order by user_id like this :

```
SELECT user_id,subscription_id,category_id
FROM subscriptions as s
ORDER BY user_id
```

And use a loop to convert the **list** to a **list of dicts** and each dict has a key (user_id).

Because all the same user_id's item will be sat on the list side by side, it only need O(n) to do this post process.